# orderitem_set.all() returning empty query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
def cart(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        print(items)
    else:
        items = []
    
    return render(request, 'product_pages/cart.html', {'items': items})
```

**everythings fine till that items value, because items returning empty query. And this is returned message to terminal.**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 04, 2022 - 10:17:16
Django version 4.1, using settings 'lira_gold_site.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2
<QuerySet []>
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:18] "GET /cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4646
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:18] "GET /static/css/navbar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1872
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:18] "GET /static/css/cart.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1108
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:18] "GET /static/fontawesomefree/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 101784
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:18] "GET /static/fontawesomefree/js/all.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1528342
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:19] "GET /static/images/lira_gold_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4517
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:19] "GET /static/fontawesomefree/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 150472
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[04/Oct/2022 10:17:19] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3822
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django items = order.orderitem\_set.all() returning empty value for quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728416/django-items-order-orderitem-set-all-returning-empty-value-for-quantity)

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine, you always get a new object

```
def cart(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
        if created:
            items = []
            print('you dont have any items in order')
        else:
            items = order.orderitem_set.all()
            print(items)
    else:
        items = []
    
    return render(request, 'product_pages/cart.html', {'items': items})
```

or you don't have any item in order. Please check it

Comment: So i copied/pasted your code and created returned false. I checked all elements that connected to this code and everything look fine, i have item in order, but i guess the problem is in between orderItem and Order class. So im going to rewrite these classes and returning to you.

Comment: So yesterday i did same codes on a different project and now i copied all of that code, pasted to current project and it did not worked on my current project but its working on my other project without any error.